# How to achieve LDAP authentication for DASH Plotly app?

Tags: python, authentication, ldap, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have created a simple DASH plotly application.
I need to do LDAP authentication for the users. 
The application should support multiple users at a time.

I checked on few references but nothing helped. I prefer not to use any 3rd party opensource products like keycloak, ngninx.

Some help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Get [Basic Auth](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication#basic-auth) running. Then fork https://github.com/plotly/dash-auth and change the `is_authorized` function in the file `dash_auth/basic_auth.py` to your needs, i.e. make it only return true if the given username and password can login to your LDAP server, for which you probably have to use a LDAP library. After that build your altered dash-auth package and install it over the one that ships with Dash.

You can also serve your app via gunicorn and make it use TLS, so your user's credentials are protected.

Comment: v. nice, super quick solution for requiring auth on dash apps :D

Comment: Can you please explain it to beginners? I have a Dash app and I want to connect it to another application built in .Net stack. It uses a multi-tenant system. I want my Dash app to show the data of a given tenant/ user, and its respective data is shown from the database. How would I achieve that? Where will I build the Dash authentication page? Please help me...

Comment: This answer is only concerned with achieving LDAP authorization and further data exchange is not addressed. For authorization, first try to use basic dash auth with this [guide](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication#basic-auth), if this works, fork dash-auth, implement the LDAP authentification as described in the answer, then build and install your dash-auth python package over the one that ships with dash and then you should be good to go.